# What is the proper/preferable SE site to ask about the code to use to calculate the hash of a password that is saved in a database?

Tags: discussion, stack-exchange, site-recommendation

I have working code that calculates the hash value of a password, which is then saved in a database. I want to change it with other code, and I want to know which implementation I should preferably use between the existing code, and two alternative implementations.

Is there a Stack Exchange site where I can ask the question, or is Stack Overflow the site I should use?

Comment: If it's well asked, Stack Overflow. I'd submit that this topic has probably been beaten to death on Stack Overflow, so take care not to post an exact duplicate.

Comment: Thank you, @GeorgeStocker. I think the code I would ask for (the current implementation) is quite specific, but I will first check a similar question has not been asked.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At the stage where you're looking for the right algorithm or protocol to do something in a secure way, ask on [Security](https://security.stackexchange.com/). While your question could be on-topic on [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/) or [Programmers](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/) as well, the quality of answers is far more likely to be good on Security.SE (and, in particular, you're far less likely to get poor advice with a lot of upvotes).

This particular question has been beaten to death, so please don't re-ask it. Read [How to securely hash passwords?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/211/how-to-securely-hash-passwords), [Do any security experts recommend bcrypt for password storage?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/4781/do-any-security-experts-recommend-bcrypt-for-password-storage), [Are there more modern password hashing methods than bcrypt and scrypt?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/5605/are-there-more-modern-password-hashing-methods-than-bcrypt-and-scrypt), and I could go on.

Once you're at the implementation stage, having picked an algorithm (PBKDF2, bcrypt or scrypt), if you have concrete difficulties with the implementation, ask on [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/).

If you have working code, you can ask for a review of a reasonable-sized piece on [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/). You might want to advertise the question on the [Sec.SE chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/151/the-dmz).

Answer (score 3):

Stack Overflow should be the site to use as long as you word it carefully. I foresee this getting closed in its current state.

[Here's a link on SO to some similar questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=code+to+use+to+calculate+the+hash+of+a+password+that+is+saved+in+a+database%3F)

Your exact question: 
"I want to know which implementation I should **preferably** use between the existing code, and two alternative implementations"

Anytime you add a word like preferable in there it becomes subjective (or sounds that way) so I'd say something more like:

"With language X. Is implementation Y or Z, the more standardized way to implement a solution to my [define problem]?"

Then add some of your searches that lead you to this being inconclusive and thus the reason you asked on SO. That should make for a good question that can be answered via facts. (Standards aren't typically subjective)